How do I delete all items except the first (index 0) and the last (index 299) using fo-dicom?
I would much appreciate your time to review this.  I have a nested sequence that contains 300 items.

How do I delete all items except the first (index 0) and the last (index will change but in this case is 299)?
I have tried this so far:
try
{
// Get the number of items in the Beam sequence    
var  bmSQ1 = dicomDataset.GetSequence(DicomTag.BeamSequence).Items.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < bmSQ1; i++)
    {
//  Get number of items in the ControlPoint Sequence
        var cpSQ = dicomDataset.GetSequence(DicomTag.BeamSequence).Items[i].GetSequence(DicomTag.ControlPointSequence).Items.Count();
var delItems = dicomDataset.GetSequence(DicomTag.BeamSequence).Items[i].GetSequence(DicomTag.ControlPointSequence).Items;
        for (int y = 0; y < cpSQ-1 ; y++)
        {
            // Go inside each item in the ControlPoint sequence and get the ControlPoint Index #
            var cpIndex = dicomDataset.GetSequence(DicomTag.BeamSequence).Items[i].GetSequence(DicomTag.ControlPointSequence).Items[y].GetSingleValueOrDefault<string>(DicomTag.ControlPointIndex, "");
                                          
            int newCP = cpSQ ;
            string totalCPs = newCP.ToString();

            // If is not the first (#0 ) or the last (totalCPs) execute the block
            if (cpIndex != "0" && cpIndex != totalCPs)

            {
                // Console.WriteLine($"Remaining ControlPoint Index#:{cpIndex}");--correct output
                delItems.RemoveAt(i); --index out of range error
                 //      delItems.RemoveAt(y); -- index out of range error                          
            }

        }

    }

delItems.RemoveAt(?) method is triggering the error
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Usually this kind of loop-to-delete scenario is resolved looping from the last index toward the first index.

Would this work? if (delItems.Count > 2) { delItems = [delItems[0], delItems[^1]]; }

Many thanks for the recommendation (Interesting piece of code!).  My application was targeting Net4.8 but recreated core8.0 just to see if it would work.
Replace the if (cpIndex != "0" && cpIndex != totalCPs) by
if (delItems.Count > 2) { delItems = [delItems[0], delItems[^1]]; but did not delete any items.

Could you  create a new "data set" and simply add the first and last items to it. Then, once you are finished forget about the original set.

first of all, your index that iterates the ControlPoints is y, so you would have to call delItems.RemoveAt(y);, but this will fail.
Say you have 10 items in your list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Then you have the loop, where y iterates from 0 to 9. When y is 1, then you decide to remove this element and you call RemoveAt(1), this leads to the list [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] containing of 9 elements.
Then on the next stept when y is 2, you decide to remove the lement and now call RemoveAt(2). Since the element 1 was already removed, all other items are slided down, so you now would remove the element 3, resulting to the list [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 9] with 8 elements.
You see, with that algorithm you remove only every second element and the list shrinks down while the index y iterates. And when y is higher then the half of cpSQ, then the list is already shorter than your y-index, and then you get the IndexOutOfRange exception.
You should use another strategy: instead of removing items from the dataset, you should create a new DicomSequence, and while you iterate over the ControlPoints, you then should add the first and the last entry into your new DicomSeqence. And then after the loop you replace the old Sequence of your controlpoints by the new created Sequence of controlpoints.
And do not forget, also to update the DicomTag 300A,0110 "Number of Control Points" when you change the DicomSequence 300A,0111 "Control Points Sequence"
